# How do I find duplicate values across multiple columns in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database-design, count, duplicates

I have a table like this

[image]

I want to check the all rows in Column A with column B and get the count of duplicates.

For example, I want to get the

```
count of 12 as 3(2 times in A+1 time in B)   
count of 11 as 2(2 times in A+0 time in B)   
count of 13 as 2(1 time in A+0 time in B)
```

How can I acheive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine all values in A and B then do the group by.
Then only select those values found in column A.

```
Select A, count(A) as cnt
From (
  Select A
  from yourTable
  Union All
  Select B 
  from yourTable) t
Where t.A in
(select distinct A from yourTable)
Group by t.A
Order by t.A;
```

Result:

```
A   cnt
11  2
12  3
13  1
```

See demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fcfe9/3

Comment: Thanks. Im using mobile so formatting is very limited

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the total occurrences from a `union all`.  A `where` clause can show only the values that occur in the `A` column:

```
select  nr
,       count(*)
from    (
        select  A as nr
        from    YourTable
        union all
        select  B
        from    YourTable
        ) sub
where   nr in -- only values that occur at least once in the A column
        (
        select  A
        from    YourTable
        )
group by
        nr
having  count(*) > 1  -- show only duplicates
```

Comment: I want to get only A columns entry. This query returns both columns

Comment: Answer edited to limit the result to values that occur in the `A` column. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @Andomar, i think you should add HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1, as OP want only duplicates